.NET MAUI: Publishing iOS for ad-hoc distribution
When publishing for android, I can generate an ad-hoc distribution, so that I can create an APK installer file to install in any Android device.
I need to do the same, but for iOS.
My research shows:

In order to do an ad-hoc distribution, I need an Apple membership
Membership costs USD 100

Can I publish to a file so that I can send it to a colleague of mine to install it on his iPhone without the above restrictions?

You can send workflow scripts and web apps without needing to sign code on iOS. Side loading applications on iOS requires a jailbreak or other code signing avenues and most require registration and payment but some may be free.
See here for what you can do for free (like send the code to your friend and have them compile it and install it on their device for free).
If you don’t want paid membership, the current fee-waiver program is linked below covering educational, government and non-profit organizational waivers.

https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/
https://developer.apple.com/support/fee-waiver/

In your case, sending them an Xcode project to compile and install for free seems the closest to what I presume your needs are.
